# How to retrieve all tab names or labels without selecting tab in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, label, jquery-ui-tabs

How to retrieve all tab names or labels without selecting tab in jQuery?

I need this to validate tab name/label length.

Comment: You need to expand on this please, otherwise we're not going to be able to help. Which tabs are you referring to?

Comment: Yeah... we need a code sample of your HTML. At least the tabs part.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jquery tabs then

```
$('.ui-tabs-nav li')
```

should give you all the tab list elements.

```
$('label')
```

should give you all the lables on the page.